# Dual boot Ubuntu(latest) and Windows 10 on Msi H170M Pro-Vdh using Msi Click Bios 5

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-partition

I have recently installed Ubuntu on additional partitions on my secondary hard disk. The installation seems to have worked, but I can't find a way to actually boot to Ubuntu. Arranging the boot order didn't work,  it seems the secondary drive is completely, with all its partitions being ignored. 
Did I do something wrong or is it just not working with this kind of system?

EDIT: BootInfo: http://paste2.org/wwXXJ1ZY

Comment: Did you install in UEFI with gpt partitioning or the 35 year old BIOS with MBR. And if UEFI do you have an ESP - efi system partition on sda. That is the only way grub installs. Or if BIOS, do you have a bios_grub partition on drive you installed grub to, if gpt partitioned. If MBR, it should just install grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred I'm pretty sure I'm running UEFI. I also saw an ESP on sda, but I can't access any of that drive's partitions from the live-cd booted Ubuntu, I think because Windows is on there. That is everything I know until this moment, gonna do the boot info in a few hours because it's past 1 am and I wanna get some sleep.

Comment: @oldfred my BootInfo:  http://paste2.org/wwXXJ1ZY

Comment: Did you try the re-install of grub, or the total uninstall/reinstall of grub when booted in UEFI mode using Boot-Repair? You do show BIOS boot versions of grub in sdb's MBR and PBR of sdb3. Those will never be used in UEFI, but not worth erasing. Not familiar with grub2win. It also looks like you left fast start up on in Windows. That should be off if you want to share a NTFS data partiton. Best not to mount or write into the Windows system partition.

Comment: @oldfred I'm not really sure, but I think it was the reinstall, I used some command using chroot on the live-boot I researched. But when I installed Ubuntu, I had thought that the stock Windows bootloader would by itself recognize Ubuntu on the secondary drive, so I don't know much. As it comes to grub2win, it is supposed to install grub from Windows instead of installing it from Ubuntu, but that only worked when I rebooted after having used the grub2win installer.

Comment: Windows will not by default boot grub/Ubuntu. You can manually add entries to BCD (see note at end of Boot-Repair's report). Grub will add Windows to grub menu if both systems are in same boot mode or both UEFI boot like you have. But grub only boots working Windows or no hibernation (fast start up) nor chkdsk needed. But with UEFI you can always directly boot from UEFI or one time boot key. Perhaps your grub2win is automating some of the work arounds?

Comment: @oldfred I'm having a bit of trouble following you, but are you saying I have to edit the BCD using tools on Windows?

Comment: Yes, did you look at lines 1273 thru 1276 in your Boot-Repair summary report? Other work arounds for some brands of computers that only want to boot Windows. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @oldfred I GOT IT TO WORK. Turns out I just didn't pay attention and forgot to use the Ubuntu boot repair, because once I had used it, it worked. It would have propably taken me even longer without your help, so thank you very much! Is there a way to close this page, so no one accidentally starts writing another answer unnessecarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often Boot-Repair can fix booting type issues with Ubuntu and some other Linux. It can only do very minor fixes to Windows issues. One fix often is just a install of grub to MBR if BIOS or to ESP if UEFI. But some need advanced options and full reinstall of grub.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Occasionally with complex configurations, it is better to have someone who understands issues review details. You can post the Summary Report from Boot-Repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Boot-Repair will not create partitions, with gpt partitioning you may need either the ESP - efi system partition(UEFI boot) or a bios_grub partition(BIOS boot).
If older BIOS/MBR, it does not require additional partitions.

[How to prepare a disk on an EFI based PC for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu)

Boot-Repair can create a copy of shimx64.efi as /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi if you tick/check the     'Use the standard EFI file' in advanced options.
Boot-Repair also suggests one of several alternative methods (BCD edit) to get UEFI systems that only want to boot Windows. Other methods:

[Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789)